# Is there a way to reference firebase storage in UserProfileChangeRequest setDisplayName

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

This is the method:

```
setDisplayName(Uri uri)
```

Is there a way to reference a direct firebase storage path to it? like

gs://project.appspot.com/default/profile_image.jpg or just /default/profile_image.jpg

Or can you only use this:

```
setPhotoUri(Uri.parse("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/project.appspot.com/o/default%2Fprofile_image.jpg?alt=media&token=0d9efwe097-dddd-4asd4ewfw4e267b7ad8"));
```

Comment: I recommend using the HTTPS URL, is there a reason you want to use the GS URI?

Comment: https with token and all feels dirty, but ok thanks il just use it